# Converting a SQL statment to criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

The SQL statement:

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers where city ='berlin'
```

…and I need to convert it to a criteria, currently I have:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria =
                forClass(Customers.class).add(
                        Restrictions.eq("city", "berlin"));
```

How do I add the `CustomerName` part into this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Customers class mapped on hibernate (using xml file or class annotations). Hibernate will do the rest for you.

You can read more here: http://hibernate.org/orm/